# Jar file versus reference to the Android Library

Tags: android, jar

You will really make my day by explaining the following nuissance.

L is a library.  A is an application using L, CA is a class, declared in A extending a class CL in the library L.

Untill recently, I could just place L.jar in the lib folder of A project. But I purchased a new hard disk, reset Eclipse, ADT plugin and SDK, then transferred my project to the new location. This is when it started.

If I place in A a reference to the project L (via Project/Properties/Android/Library), everything still works all right. But with a jar file, it gives a "No Class Defintion Found" error for CA class, even though it belongs to the same class as the calling method!

To avoid some sceptical remarks:

1. L has no resources in it.
2. Compiler version is 1.6
3. I cleaned both projects millions of times.
4. Both projects are compiled with same API version.
5. No obfuscation was used and I checked that CL class is really present in L.jar.
6. Tried placing L.jar in build path, as topmost, then as bottommost - no help.

Thank you for anticipated help.

Comment: Are you exporting the symbols of L (in the last tab)?  Is L above your src folder in the list of imports?

Answer (score 0):

It was rather silly of me: in "Order and Export" panel of BuildPath configuration I had Android Dependencies ticked, but Android Provite Libraries unticked.

What I found out is that libraries linked through Android properties go to Android Dependencies, whereas the ones in lib folder are considered as Android Private. This explains why the first were included, while second weren't.

The most annoying thing is that Eclipse doesn't complain, the build seems to be all right, and only at the execution stage the error comes out. As a C programmer I am not quite used to that :)